# Function for calculating next string

Tags: c#

I need a function for getting next string, but the logic is different here. I want to increment input alphabet A to B, B to C until Z. But after Z I need to get string A1. When I get string A1 as input it needs to be incremented to B1, B1 to C1 until Z1. After Z1 I should get A2. When I get A2 it should increment it to B2 and so on till Z9. Can somebody help.

I tried using below code but it gives me wrong output when I give input A1 it gives me output as A2.

What I have tried:

```
public static string Increment(string input){
  List<char> chars = input.ToList();
  for (int i = chars.Count - 1; i >= 0; i++)
  {
    if (chars[i] < '1' || chars[i] > '9')
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("");
    }
    chars[i]++;
    if (chars[i] > 'Z')
    {
      chars[i] = 'A';
      if (i == 0)
      {
        chars.Add('1');
      }
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  return string.concat(chars);
}
```

Comment: This isn't real code becaue `.concat` won't compile. It must be `.Concat`. :/

Comment: Your `for` is probably wrong. You start at the last index, but you increment the index. I think you ment `i--` instead of `i++`.

Comment: What happens after Z9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started at the last index and increment it, that's why you get A2.

You could try this:

```
  public static string Increment(string input)
        {
            List<char> chars = input.ToList();
            chars[0]++;
            if (chars[0] > 'Z')
            {
                chars[0] = 'A';
                if (input.Length == 1)
                {
                    chars.Add('1');
                }
                else
                {
                    chars[1]++;
                }
            }
            return string.Concat(chars);
        }
```

Comment: You need to add like this List<char> chars = input.ToUpper().ToList();

Comment: Thanks a lot for the everyone for the answer. I will test all of them for my understanding. @Darwin my code is similar to yours I was just not able to correct it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, your welcome, I tried to make it like yours

Answer (score 3):

I find that it always helps to create a type to handle this sort of thing.

Here's a simple struct with some basic operations:

**NOTE!** The whole thing has **not** been thoroughly tested.

```
public struct AlphaNumericId : IEquatable<AlphaNumericId>, IComparable<AlphaNumericId>
{
    private static readonly Regex _ParsePattern = new Regex(@"^(?<letter>[A-Z])(?<number>\d*)$");
    private readonly int _Value;

    public AlphaNumericId(int value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), "value cannot be negative");

        _Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        int letter = _Value % 26;
        int number = _Value / 26;

        var sb = new StringBuilder(5);
        sb.Append((char)('A' + letter));
        if (number > 0)
            sb.Append(number);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static AlphaNumericId Parse(string input)
    {
        if (TryParse(input, out var value))
            return value;
        throw new FormatException($"Unable to parse '{input}' as an AlphaNumericId");
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string input, out AlphaNumericId value)
    {
        value = default;

        var match = _ParsePattern.Match(input);
        if (!match.Success)
            return false;
        
        char letter = match.Groups["letter"].Value[0];
        string letterString = match.Groups["number"].Value;
        int number = 0;
        if (letterString.Length > 0)
            if (!int.TryParse(letterString, out number))
                return false;
                
        value = new AlphaNumericId(number * 26 + (letter - 'A'));
        return true;
    }

    public static AlphaNumericId operator ++(AlphaNumericId input) => new AlphaNumericId(input._Value + 1);
    public static AlphaNumericId operator --(AlphaNumericId input) => new AlphaNumericId(input._Value - 1);

    public static AlphaNumericId operator +(AlphaNumericId input, int offset) => new AlphaNumericId(input._Value + offset);
    public static AlphaNumericId operator -(AlphaNumericId input, int offset) => new AlphaNumericId(input._Value - offset);
    public static int operator -(AlphaNumericId input, AlphaNumericId other) => input._Value - other._Value;
    
    public static bool operator <(AlphaNumericId a, AlphaNumericId b) => a._Value < b._Value;
    public static bool operator >(AlphaNumericId a, AlphaNumericId b) => a._Value > b._Value;
    public static bool operator ==(AlphaNumericId a, AlphaNumericId b) => a._Value == b._Value;
    public static bool operator !=(AlphaNumericId a, AlphaNumericId b) => a._Value != b._Value;

    public override int GetHashCode() => _Value.GetHashCode() ^ 37;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is AlphaNumericId other)
            return Equals(other);
        return false;
    }
    
    public bool Equals(AlphaNumericId other) => _Value == other._Value;
    public int CompareTo(AlphaNumericId other) => _Value.CompareTo(other._Value);

    public static explicit operator int(AlphaNumericId id) => id._Value;
    public static explicit operator AlphaNumericId(int value) => new AlphaNumericId(value);
}
```

A "next" method would simply be:

```
return (AlphaNumericId.Parse(input) + 1).ToString();
```

Or you could simply keep the whole thing in an AlphaNumericId type all the way, and the next value would then be either of the following:

```
input += 1;
input++;
```

Since the type also allows for conversion to and from an integer, here are the first 100 id's:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => (AlphaNumericId)i)
```

which will generate `A, B, C, D, ..., Z, A1, A2, ..., Z2, ..., V3`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solution helps you

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter String");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                Console.WriteLine(Increment(input.ToUpper()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static string Increment(string input)
        {
            List<char> chars = input.ToList();
            var result = new List<string>();
            result.Add(string.Concat(chars));
            while (string.Concat(chars) != "Z9")
            {
                chars[0]++;
                if (chars[0] > 'Z')
                {
                    chars[0] = 'A';
                    if (input.Length == 1)
                    {
                        chars.Add('1');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chars[1]++;
                    }
                }
                result.Add(string.Concat(chars));
            }
            return string.Join(",", result);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

[image: Outpu]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version:

```
public static string Increment(string input)
    => (input[0] != 'Z') 
        ? input.Replace(input[0],(char)(input[0] + 1))
        : $"A{int.Parse(input.Substring(1)) + 1}";
```

Or in a more expressive format:

```
public static string Increment(string input)
{
    var letter = input[0];
    if(letter != 'Z') 
    {
        var nextLetter = (char)(letter + 1);
        return input.Replace(letter,nextLetter); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        var number = int.Parse(input.Substring(1));
        return $"A{number + 1}";
    }
}
```

The first 100 elements:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 I1 J1 K1 L1 M1 N1 O1 P1 Q1 R1 S1 T1 U1 V1 W1 X1 Y1 Z1 
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 I2 J2 K2 L2 M2 N2 O2 P2 Q2 R2 S2 T2 U2 V2 W2 X2 Y2 Z2 
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3 I3 J3 K3 L3 M3 N3 O3 P3 Q3 R3 S3 T3 U3 V3 W3 X3 Y3 Z3 
A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4 I4 J4 K4 L4 M4 N4 O4 P4 Q4 R4 S4 T4 U4 V4 W4
```

Comment: I like the terseness.

Answer (score 0):

```
static string AsSpecial(int number)
{
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var letterIndex = number % letters.Length;
    var exp = number / letters.Length;

    return exp > 0 ? $"{letters[letterIndex]}{exp}" : $"{letters[letterIndex]}";
}

static int AsNumber(string special)
{
    var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(special))
        return -1;

    if (special.Length > 2)
        return -1;

    var letter = special[0];
    var exp = special.Length == 2 ? int.Parse(special.Substring(1, 1)) : 0;

    return exp * letters.Length + letters.IndexOf(letter);
}
```

Can be called with:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);

foreach (var value in values)
{
    var special = AsSpecial(value);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{special} -> {AsNumber(special)}");
}
```